# Getting this error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." inside a react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, recaptcha

I am receiving this error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." when I try and run my function. I am trying to run a script that generates a reCaptcha token the script is as follows:

> This component should generate the token(this is where I get the
> error)

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { RECAPTCHA_KEY } from '../../../utils/env'

// @ts-ignore
declare const window: any

interface RecaptchaProps {
  actionType: string
}
export const RecaptchaGen = ({ actionType }: RecaptchaProps) => {
  const siteKey = RECAPTCHA_KEY
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const scriptTag = document.createElement('script')
    scriptTag.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=' + siteKey
    document.appendChild(scriptTag)

    return () => {
      scriptTag.remove()
      setLoaded(false)
    }
  }, [siteKey])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded) return
    window.grecaptcha.ready(function () {
      window.grecaptcha
        .execute(siteKey, {
          action: actionType,
        })
        .then(function (token: string) {
          //reCaptch token generated needs to be sent to the back end for validation
          console.log(token)
        })
    })
  }, [loaded, actionType, siteKey])
}
```

> Here within another component, I call the prior script component with
> an action type passed through but I get the react hook error
> mentioned(only showing relevant code snipets).

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { RecaptchaGen } from '../../../components/_molecules/Recaptcha'

const onLoginClick = () => {
    RecaptchaGen({ actionType: 'login' })
  }
```

I presume the issue is the way I am calling/using the imported component but I can't find a solution?

Comment: You are breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) namely calling a React hook ***outside*** a React function. `RecaptchaGen` could be redefined (i.e. renamed) to be a custom React hook, but then you've still the issue of *it* being conditionally called from an `onClick` handler. Are you wanting to generate a recaptcha when a login button is clicked?

Comment: I am not familiar with your specific use case, but a common pattern is to encapsulate some of the effect logic into a function that is returned by your custom hook, then any normal JS function (callback or not) can invoke *that* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with your specific use case, but a common pattern is to encapsulate some of the effect logic into a function that is returned by your custom hook, then any normal JS function (callback or not) can invoke *that* function.

1. Rename `RecaptchaGen` to `useRecaptchaGen` so it can be used as a React hook.
2. Return a function to basically replace the second `useEffect` callback.

   ```
   export const useRecaptchaGen = ({ actionType }: RecaptchaProps) => {
     const siteKey = RECAPTCHA_KEY
     const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false)
     React.useEffect(() => {
       const scriptTag = document.createElement('script')
       scriptTag.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=' + siteKey
       document.appendChild(scriptTag)

       return () => {
         scriptTag.remove()
         setLoaded(false)
       }
     }, [siteKey]);

     const generateRecaptcha = () => {
       if (!loaded) return;
       window.grecaptcha.ready(function () {
         window.grecaptcha
           .execute(siteKey, {
             action: actionType,
           })
           .then(function (token: string) {
             //reCaptch token generated needs to be sent to the back end for validation
             console.log(token)
           })
       })
     };

     return { generateRecaptcha };
   }
   ```
3. In the component use the new hook and destructure `generateRecaptcha`.

   ```
   const { generateRecaptcha } = useRecaptchaGen({ actionType: 'login' });
   ```
4. Invoke `generateRecaptcha` in the `onLoginClick` handler.

   ```
   const onLoginClick = () => {
     generateRecaptcha();
   }
   ```

Comment: Wow thank you! I will test this out this morning and get back to you!

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you for your easy solution

Answer (score 1):

You are using `useEffect` hook inside regular `js` function.

`hooks` can only be called inside valid react component. `RepcaptchaGen` is not a react component because its not using react component specific things like returning some `jsx`.

Answer (score 1):

The name `RecaptchaGen` would suggest it is a constructor function or component but it's neither. it is a custom hook so should start with `use`, for exampele: useRecaptchaGen.

Here is how you can use it in your component:

```
export const useRecaptchaGen = (action) => {
  if (!action) {
    return;
  }
  const { actionType }: RecaptchaProps = action;
  //....rest of your code
};

const Component = () => {
  const [action, setAction] = React.useState(false);
  const onLoginClick = () => {
    setAction({ actionType: 'login' });
  };
  //cannot conditionally call hooks
  useRecaptchaGen(action);
};
```

Comment: Thanks mate that solution would work great!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you aren't returning any code in your RecaptchaGen function. A JSX return, among other things, is what differentiates a React Functional component from a regular javascript function, and a regular javascript function can't use hooks. If you want to fix this, add a return statement.